# Different results when Sorting a Excel file using pandas and pywin32 api

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sorting

I want to sort a excel file which contains data like this:

```
1.jpg
CC Library - Screen for proxy.png
aAd.ai
aaa.PSD
automation_35.jpg
automation_36.jpg
automation_37.jpg
automation_371.jpg
sad.psd
sde-Recovered.ai
sde-Recovered.psd
sde-Recovered1.psd
testfile.ai
testfile.psd
vpTestID (5)as.indd
wulogo15117.jpg
```

If I am using pandas the results I am getting using `df.sort_values` or `sort_index` is

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')

result = df.sort_index()

print(result)
```

The result is:

```
1.jpg
CC Library - Screen for proxy.png
aAd.ai
aaa.PSD
automation_35.jpg
automation_36.jpg
automation_37.jpg
automation_371.jpg
sad.psd
sde-Recovered.ai
sde-Recovered.psd
sde-Recovered1.psd
testfile.ai
testfile.psd
vpTestID (5)as.indd
wulogo15117.jpg
wulogo15117.jpg
```

But if I use win32api

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('data.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')

ws.Range('A1:A100').Sort(Key1=ws.Range('A1'), Order1=1, Orientation=1)

wb.Save()
excel.Application.Quit()
```

I am getting data like

```
1.jpg
aaa.PSD
aAd.ai
automation_35.jpg
automation_36.jpg
automation_37.jpg
automation_371.jpg
CC Library - Screen for proxy.png
sad.psd
sde-Recovered.ai
sde-Recovered.psd
sde-Recovered1.psd
testfile.ai
testfile.psd
vpTestID (5)as.indd
wulogo15117.jpg
```

I want data in this(The way win32api giving) format for comparison. This will work for me on Windows machines but will fail on Mac machines since it does not have win32api.

Can someone please help me in getting the data in the same format on Mac also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the values using lower (converts the string to lowercase):

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['1.jpg',
       'aAd.ai',
       'CC Library - Screen for proxy.png',
       'aaa.PSD',
       'automation_35.jpg',
       'automation_36.jpg',
       'automation_37.jpg',
       'automation_371.jpg',
       'sad.psd',
       'sde-Recovered.ai',
       'sde-Recovered.psd',
       'sde-Recovered1.psd',
       'testfile.ai',
       'testfile.psd',
       'vpTestID (5)as.indd',
       'wulogo15117.jpg']

series = pd.Series(data=sorted(lst, key=lambda e: e.lower()))
print(series)
```

**Output**

```
0                                 1.jpg
1                               aaa.PSD
2                                aAd.ai
3                     automation_35.jpg
4                     automation_36.jpg
5                     automation_37.jpg
6                    automation_371.jpg
7     CC Library - Screen for proxy.png
8                               sad.psd
9                      sde-Recovered.ai
10                    sde-Recovered.psd
11                   sde-Recovered1.psd
12                          testfile.ai
13                         testfile.psd
14                  vpTestID (5)as.indd
15                      wulogo15117.jpg
dtype: object
```